STM32 freeze at osKernelStart() after jump from bootloader
my stm32f103 freeze after osKernelStart() after jump from bootloader but if I flash at that address it run normally.
I try with blinking LED simple one but it still freeze too.
while (1)
  {
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_SIGNAL_2_GPIO_Port, LED_SIGNAL_2_Pin);
      HAL_Delay(500);
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_SIGNAL_3_GPIO_Port, LED_SIGNAL_3_Pin);
      HAL_Delay(500);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }

I using cmsis-rtos v1 (cmsis-rtos v2 in STM32CubeIDE is got error after update to 1.16.1 so I roll back to v1)
Why I know it freeze at there:
I put print at before of each task and one before osKernelStart(), only the one before osKernelStart print it, other is no, all task create successfully.
I already try:

__disable_irq() but it didn't work
All bootloader clock and application clock is same.

My setting:
STM32F103RCTX_FLASH.ld:
MEMORY
{
  RAM    (xrw)    : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 48K
  FLASH    (rx)    : ORIGIN = 0x0800C800,   LENGTH = 204K
}

system_stm32f1xx.c:
#define VECT_TAB_BASE_ADDRESS   FLASH_BASE      /*!< Vector Table base address field.
                                                     This value must be a multiple of 0x200. */
#define VECT_TAB_OFFSET         0x0000C800U     /*!< Vector Table base offset field.
                                                     This value must be a multiple of 0x200. */

my jump function:
void OTATask::_otaGotoApplication()
{
    void (*app_reset_handler)(void)=(void (*)(void))(*((volatile uint32_t*) (FLASH_APPLICATION_LOCATION + 4U)));

    /* Reset the Clock */
    HAL_RCC_DeInit();
    HAL_DeInit();
    __set_MSP(*(volatile uint32_t*) FLASH_APPLICATION_LOCATION);
    SysTick->CTRL = 0;
    SysTick->LOAD = 0;
    SysTick->VAL = 0;

    /* Jump to application */
    app_reset_handler();
}



You forgot to load SP from the first word in your app vector table.



You forgot to disable the interrupts (but not globally - you need to disable all enabled in bootloader)



Do not use HAL_Delay() in tasks only vTaskDelay or its  cmsisOS wrapper


@0___________ Thanks for reply, I already try everything you said but it still got stuck, few day before I just debug and I realize somehow my stm32 go to interrupt when it go to application and it direct to interrupt. And it got to my callback function which I put xQueueSend(....,portMAX_Delay); (this is why it freeze) But I dont know why when I flash direct it, it not auto jump to my callback function.
